# NamedEntityGraph Returns All Columns and Objects

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to utilize a NamedEntityGraph to limit the return data for specific queries. Mainly I do not want to return full object details when listing the object. A very simple class example is below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="playerreport",schema="dbo")

@NamedEntityGraphs({
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "report.simple",
        attributeNodes = 
        {@NamedAttributeNode(value="intId")
        }
        )
})
public class PlayerReportEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="intid",columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
    private String intId;

    @Column(name="plyid",columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private String plyId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "plyid", insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private PlayerEntity player;
```

No matter what I do to plyId and player are always returned. Is there any way to only return the requested columns (intId) ?

As for the collection Hibernate does not do the join for the player object but it still returns player as null. So that part is working to an extent.

I am using a JPARepository below to generate Crud Statements for me

```
public interface PlayerReportRepository extends JpaRepository<PlayerReportEntity, String> {

@EntityGraph(value="report.simple")
List<PlayerIntelEntity> findByPlyId(@Param(value = "playerId") String playerId);

@Override
@EntityGraph(value="report.simple")
public PlayerIntelEntity findOne(String id);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A chunk of text from here - "Hence it seems that the @NamedEntityGraph only affects fields that are Collections, but fields that are not a Collection are always loaded." [from JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9270)

Please use the Example 47 on [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) page and use repositories accordingly.
In essence, hibernate is right now loading all the feilds in the class and for collections it will work if you follow the example stated above.

Thanks.